# Variable name taken by keyword -- your examples?

Tags: language-design, keyword, reserved-words

Have there been any cases where you wanted to use a word as a variable/function name, but couldn't because it was a reserved word in your language?

The ones that crop up over and over again for me are `in` and `out` in C#... Those would be great names for streams, but I'm always forced to use `inn` and `outt` instead.

**EDIT:**   I'm not asking about help with this problem -- I'm trying to learn from mistakes that past language designers have made. Your answers will influence a language I'm designing.

Answer (score 1):

`type` and `object`. I don't like when my programming languages steal those :(

Comment: Why? What would the `type` or `object` variables be for? Those are horrendously undescriptive names that probably _should_ be builtins.

Comment: struct Item {
    ItemType Type;
    Item(ItemType type) {Type = type;}
}

Comment: @Chris I use them as localized variables that don't have a scope of more than a few lines. I hope you aren't using long variable names for everything.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some languages let you use any words you want anywhere. Clojure, for example:

```
(let [let "what?"] let)
=> "what?"
```

This could either be helpful or horrible depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `new` and `delete` as function pointer fields in OO-ish C code a lot, which makes porting to C++ "fun"... ugh.

This isn't really a problem for C#, though:

```
int @in;
```

There, now you have a variable named `in`.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. Keywords in a language tend to be short and general - two things that rarely make for good variable names.

Answer (score 0):

In those cases, I think of "in" and "out" as adjectives, and usually make something more descriptive, such as "inStream" and "outStream".